# Activation Specification batching MDB processing

Tags: websphere, activation, ibm-mq

I have an MQ topic with messages that expire after 2 hours. There are thousands of messages on the topic at a given time.

I am using an MDB and an Activation Specification in Websphere to process the messages. The activation spec has multiple instances configured, so that it can process the messages in parallel.

Websphere appears to be reading the messages in batches, every 5 seconds, which looks like it's wasting a lot of time - for example:

```
[8/7/23 15:10:56:791 BST] 0000012d   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:56.791
[8/7/23 15:10:56:830 BST] 0000014f   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:56.830
[8/7/23 15:10:56:830 BST] 00000127   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:56.830
[8/7/23 15:10:56:966 BST] 00000132   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:56.966
[8/7/23 15:10:57:040 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:57.040
[8/7/23 15:10:57:040 BST] 00000132   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:57.040
[8/7/23 15:10:57:040 BST] 0000012d   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:57.040
[8/7/23 15:10:57:040 BST] 00000157   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:57.040
[8/7/23 15:10:57:040 BST] 00000139   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:57.040
[8/7/23 15:10:57:040 BST] 0000014f   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:10:57.040
[8/7/23 15:11:02:421 BST] 0000015c   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:02.421
[8/7/23 15:11:02:456 BST] 00000127   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:02.456
[8/7/23 15:11:02:627 BST] 0000013b   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:02.627
[8/7/23 15:11:02:682 BST] 00000134   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:02.682
[8/7/23 15:11:02:756 BST] 0000014f   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:02.756
[8/7/23 15:11:02:767 BST] 00000157   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:02.767
[8/7/23 15:11:02:821 BST] 00000139   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:02.821
[8/7/23 15:11:06:967 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:06.967
[8/7/23 15:11:07:025 BST] 0000012d   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:07.025
[8/7/23 15:11:07:036 BST] 0000015c   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:07.035
[8/7/23 15:11:07:092 BST] 0000013b   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:07.092
[8/7/23 15:11:07:122 BST] 00000134   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:07.122
[8/7/23 15:11:07:165 BST] 0000014f   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:07.165
[8/7/23 15:11:07:207 BST] 00000127   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:07.207
[8/7/23 15:11:07:247 BST] 00000139   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:07.247
[8/7/23 15:11:07:300 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:07.300
[8/7/23 15:11:07:356 BST] 0000012d   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:07.356
[8/7/23 15:11:12:696 BST] 0000015c   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:12.696
[8/7/23 15:11:12:761 BST] 00000132   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:12.761
[8/7/23 15:11:12:827 BST] 00000134   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:12.827
[8/7/23 15:11:12:891 BST] 0000014f   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:12.891
[8/7/23 15:11:12:968 BST] 00000127   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:12.968
[8/7/23 15:11:18:327 BST] 0000015c   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.327
[8/7/23 15:11:18:359 BST] 0000015c   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.359
[8/7/23 15:11:18:359 BST] 00000127   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.359
[8/7/23 15:11:18:359 BST] 00000132   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.359
[8/7/23 15:11:18:364 BST] 0000012d   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.364
[8/7/23 15:11:18:368 BST] 00000127   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.368
[8/7/23 15:11:18:368 BST] 0000015c   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.368
[8/7/23 15:11:18:387 BST] 00000127   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.387
[8/7/23 15:11:18:423 BST] 00000157   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.423
[8/7/23 15:11:18:601 BST] 00000134   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.601
[8/7/23 15:11:18:645 BST] 0000014f   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.645
[8/7/23 15:11:18:673 BST] 0000014f   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.673
[8/7/23 15:11:18:709 BST] 0000013b   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.709
[8/7/23 15:11:18:745 BST] 00000139   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.745
[8/7/23 15:11:18:787 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.787
[8/7/23 15:11:18:827 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.827
[8/7/23 15:11:18:867 BST] 00000132   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.867
[8/7/23 15:11:18:901 BST] 0000012d   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:18.901
[8/7/23 15:11:21:992 BST] 00000127   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:21.992
[8/7/23 15:11:22:036 BST] 00000157   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.036
[8/7/23 15:11:22:085 BST] 00000134   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.085
[8/7/23 15:11:22:130 BST] 0000015c   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.130
[8/7/23 15:11:22:180 BST] 0000013b   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.180
[8/7/23 15:11:22:206 BST] 00000139   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.206
[8/7/23 15:11:22:218 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.218
[8/7/23 15:11:22:262 BST] 0000014f   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.262
[8/7/23 15:11:22:300 BST] 0000012d   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.300
[8/7/23 15:11:22:336 BST] 00000127   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.336
[8/7/23 15:11:22:374 BST] 00000157   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:22.374
[8/7/23 15:11:26:414 BST] 00000134   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:26.414
[8/7/23 15:11:26:488 BST] 0000015c   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:26.488
[8/7/23 15:11:26:568 BST] 0000013b   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:26.568
[8/7/23 15:11:26:630 BST] 00000132   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:26.630
[8/7/23 15:11:26:698 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:26.698
[8/7/23 15:11:32:124 BST] 0000014f   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.124
[8/7/23 15:11:32:195 BST] 0000012d   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.195
[8/7/23 15:11:32:214 BST] 00000157   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.214
[8/7/23 15:11:32:214 BST] 00000134   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.214
[8/7/23 15:11:32:214 BST] 00000132   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.214
[8/7/23 15:11:32:214 BST] 00000139   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.214
[8/7/23 15:11:32:215 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.215
[8/7/23 15:11:32:218 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.218
[8/7/23 15:11:32:251 BST] 00000134   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.251
[8/7/23 15:11:32:433 BST] 0000013b   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.433
[8/7/23 15:11:32:474 BST] 000000f4   1  Received message at 2023-08-07T15:11:32.474
```

How can I configure the activation specification not to wait so long between batches?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, AWS was using a burstable EFS which was capping the rate at which messages were written to the MQ topic - so it was nothing to do with the activation specification at all!